# XPath - contains function

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am using PHP and Xpath to search for data in an XML file that matches or partially matches
 a text string in any of the name elements. Here is the XML file, named products.xml:

```
<products>

<product type="Electronics">
<name>Desktop</name>
<price>499.99</price>
<store>Best Buy</store>
</product>

<product type="Hardware">
<name>Hand Saw</name>
<price>99.99</price>
<store>Lowes</store>
</product>

</products>
```

Here is the PHP and XPath code which utilizes the contains() function to search for matching or partially matching text in any of the name elements in the XML file to the text string "Desk":

```
$xmldoc = simplexml_load_file("products.xml");
$query = $xmldoc->xpath('/products/product/name[contains(text(),"Desk")]'); 
foreach($query as $Products) 
{
echo $Products->name . " ";
echo $Products->price . "<br>";
}
```

Nothing is being displayed! Any advice is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Try print_r($query); what does it say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the var_dump() function to inspect your $Products variable inside your loop:

```
foreach($query as $Products) 
{
  var_dump( $Products );
  echo $Products->name . " ";
  echo $Products->price . "<br>";
}
```

You'll see that $Products does not have a name attribute. This worked for me:

```
foreach($query as $Products) 
{
  echo $Products[0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The last path component before your selector is currently `/name`, you need to be constructing a path to `/product` and then using the selector to filter on `name`

Change

```
$query = $xmldoc->xpath('/products/product/name[contains(text(),"Desk")]');
```

To

```
$query = $xmldoc->xpath('/products/product[contains(name,"Desk")]');
```

The difference is your $query contains "name" elements not the "product" elements you're wanting.

Answer (score 0):

Or another solution is to use `getElementsByTagName`.

```
<?php
$XML='<products>

<product type="Electronics">
<name>Desktop</name>
<price>499.99</price>
<store>Best Buy</store>
</product>

<product type="Hardware">
<name>Hand Saw</name>
<price>99.99</price>
<store>Lowes</store>
</product>

</products>
';
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument;
$xmldoc->loadXML($XML);
echo $xmldoc->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0)->nodeValue;
?>
```

This should work fine for you.

Comment: You should add some filtering for a `name contains "Desk"`

Comment: If my solution is working, please upvote or accept as an answer :)